# Where to store secret keys and password in Python

Tags: python, configuration, google-maps

I have a small Python program, which uses a Google Maps API secret key.  I'm getting ready to check-in my code, and I don't want to include the secret key in SVN.

In the canonical PHP app you put secret keys, database passwords, and other app specific config in LocalSettings.php.  Is there a similar file/location which Python programmers expect to find and modify?

Comment: Thanks Vinay.  I got it to work with execfile(os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], '.appname')).  Thanks S.Lott for the execfile method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no standard location - on Windows, it's usually in the directory `os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'], 'appname')` and on Unix it's usually `os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], '.appname')`.

Answer (score 4):

A user must configure their own secret key.  A configuration file is the perfect place to keep this information.

You several choices for configuration files.

1. Use [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) to parse a config file.
2. Use a simple Python module as the configuration file.  You can simply [`execfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile) to load values from that file.
3. Invent your own configuration file notation and parse that.

Comment: +1 for the answer, but why would you use execfile over a standard import?

Comment: Because I want the "globals" loaded into a dictionary I created.  It's not a proper module and I generally don't want anything but a few globals.

Answer (score 1):

Any path can reference the user's home directory in a cross-platform way by expanding the common ~ (tilde) with `os.path.expanduser()`, like so:

```
appdir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.myapp')
```

Comment: Not quite. On my Windows machine, `os.path.expanduser('~')` expands to `C:\Documents and Settings\Vinay Sajip` which is not the recommended place to put application data. That recommended place is specified by the environment variable `APPDATA`, as I mentioned in my answer.

Note that the question was asking where to store application configuration data, not how to find the user's home directory. Not the same thing!